# accessing a reference variable terminates the program

Tags: c++, oop, qt, pass-by-reference

My program terminates when I refer to the properties of the referenced variable src_.
The main idea of the code is that the MainWindow class calls SettingsWindow class to show some settings. There are also two additional classes which take care of the saved settings, those are ConfigSource and the ConfigUpdater. src_ is defined as a referenced variable inside ConfigUpdater. Here's the code:

inside MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ConfigSource cfg;

        settings = new SettingsWindow(cfg,this);

        settings->print_config(cfg.config());
...
```

SettingsWindow Header and source:

```
#ifndef SETTINGSWINDOW_H
#define SETTINGSWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QModelIndex>

#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QTimer>

#include "cameracommands.h"

struct Config
{
    /* General Options */
    QString general_key_lock;
    QString general_back_light;
};

class ConfigSource 
{
    public:

    ConfigSource() {
        qDebug() << "inside configSource :))";
        config_.general_aperture_control   = "Reset";
        config_.general_automatic_exposure = "Full Auto";

    }

    Config config() const {return config_;}

    void setConfig(const Config& cfg) {config_ = cfg;}

//        Config config_;
    private:
    Config config_;
};

class ConfigUpdater : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ConfigUpdater(ConfigSource& src) : src_(src) {}

public slots:

    void apply () {src_.setConfig(tempConfig_);}
    void cancel() {tempConfig_ = src_.config();}

public:

    void updateGeneralBackLight(QString s)             {tempConfig_.general_back_light         = s; qDebug() << "BackLight updated :)";}
    void updateGeneralKeyLock(QString s)               {tempConfig_.general_key_lock           = s; qDebug() << "KeyLock updated :)";}

    Config tempConfig_;
    ConfigSource& src_;
};

//----------------------------

namespace Ui {
    class SettingsWindow;
}

class SettingsWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SettingsWindow(ConfigSource &src, QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~SettingsWindow();

    void print_config(Config cfg);

signals:
    void clicked(const QString &text);
    void sendToPLC(QByteArray );

public slots:
    void updateGeneralBackLight();
    void updateGeneralKeyLock();

private:

    void set_mappings();

    Ui::SettingsWindow *ui;
    ConfigUpdater      *config_updater;
};

#endif // SETTINGSWINDOW_H
```

Settings source file

```
SettingsWindow::SettingsWindow(ConfigSource &src, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SettingsWindow)
{
    /* initializations */
    ui->setupUi(this);
    config_updater = new ConfigUpdater(src);
```

This part is critical, when I try to access src_ from apply and cancel slots, program terminates, example:

```
void SettingsWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked() //apply
{
    qDebug() << "Apply Button";

    print_config(config_updater->src_.config());
    config_updater->apply();
    print_config(config_updater->src_.config());
}

void SettingsWindow::print_config(Config config)
{
    qDebug() << config.general_key_lock;
    qDebug() << config.general_back_light;
}

void SettingsWindow::on_sendToMainButton_clicked() /* cancel */
{
   print_config(config_updater->tempConfig_);

   config_updater->cancel();

   print_config(config_updater->tempConfig_);

   print_config(config_updater->src_.config_);
}
```

Though, printing the _tempconfig variable works fine! I removed some button slots from the header file for simplicity.

I would thank if you show me how to solve this bug : )

Comment: Show us the error you are getting and the bit of code causing it. A shorter example which replicates and isolates the problem would be much better as well. It sounds like you are using a reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigSource cfg;` is local to the constructor of `MainWindow`.

When the signals responsible for invoking the slots where the crash occurs, the `MainWindow` constructor has long finished executing (even if the `MainWindow` instance is still around), so the reference is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigSource` object is created as a local variable in the `MainWindow` constructor, so it is destroyed at the end of that constructor and all other references become invalid.

You could declare it as a member of `MainWindow` to increase its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially the same problem as you had when you asked this question before.

Earlier ConfigSource was local to the SettingsWindow constructor so it got destroyed too early. Now ConfigSource is local to the MainWindow constructor so it gets destroyed when the MainWindow constructor exits, but this is still too early! The ConfigSource object must live at least as long as the SettingWindow object. One way would be to put the ConfigSource object inside the SettingsWindow object but I seem to remember that you didn't want to do that. Another way would be to declare the ConfigSource object in main (so it lives as long as the program does) and pass it down via references to the SettingWindow constructor.

Only you know the structure of your code, you just have to get a handle on how long your objects live, and remember that the ConfigSource object must live at least as long as the SettingWindow object. You really need to get this idea straight in your head otherwise you going to run into these problems a lot.

Comment: thanks. I don't think it does make any difference to declare the ConfigSource inside Main window class or in the main program. as long as the Main window is always the last window to get closed by the user. or inside the Settings class, would it be ?

Comment: I think any of those three places would work, in main function, in MainWindow class, in SettingsWindow class.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers explain this nicely (`ConfigSource cfg;` is local to your MainWindow's constructor thus the memory gets reclaimed after the constructor finishes).

The fix - use heap allocation (via operator `new`)

Comment: is it a good idea to define ConfigSource inside MainWindow? I know that the temporary value of src_ will be kept as I use that reference in the ConfigUpdater class. I did declared the initial point inside MainWindow constructor, because before the MainWindow gets destroyed or closed by the user, I can update the value of the latest config src_ to a FILE! is there a better idea to make the structure and the code neat?

Comment: This is wrong 'I did declared the initial point inside MainWindow constructor, because before the MainWindow gets destroyed or closed by the user' The MainWindow constructor exits, anything declared inside it gets destroyed, this has nothing to do with the user closing the window, which happens later.